# How to add an text in a Python / Tkinter text

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I have a question about Python/Tkinter. I want to add text
before the number of sport activities in a `Tk.Label`.
For Example I want to write 'Kalorien:' before the int `Kalorien` in the textfield `Kalorien_fen`

```
def Kalorienzähler():

fenster1=tk.Tk()
fenster1.wm_geometry('800x480')
Kalorien_fen =  tk.Label(fenster1, text= (Kalorien)  )
Kalorien_fen.config(font=('Arial', 62))
Kalorien_fen.pack()
Liegestütze_fen = tk.Label(fenster1,text= (Liegestütze))
Liegestütze_fen.config(font=('Arial', 62))
Liegestütze_fen.pack()
Kniebeuge_fen = tk.Label(fenster1,text= (Kniebeuge))
Kniebeuge_fen.config(font=('Arial', 62))
Kniebeuge_fen.pack()
Planks_fen = tk.Label(fenster1,text= (Planks))
Planks_fen.config(font=('Arial', 62))
Planks_fen.pack()
Hampelmann_fen = tk.Label(fenster1,text= (Hampelmann))
Hampelmann_fen.config(font=('Arial', 62))
Hampelmann_fen.pack()






Aufgabe=random.choice(Sport_liste)
fenster=tk.Tk()
fenster.wm_geometry('800x480')
text =  tk.Label(master=fenster, text= Aufgabe)
text.config(font=('Arial', 72))
text.pack()
if Aufgabe == 'Liegestütze 5x ':
    Kalorien += 1
    Liegestütze += 5
if Aufgabe == 'Liegestütze 10x ':
    Kalorien += 2
    Liegestütze += 10
if Aufgabe == 'Kniebeuge 15X':
    Kalorien += 2.5
    Kniebeuge += 10
if Aufgabe == 'Kniebeuge 10x':
    Kalorien += 3.5
    Kniebeuge += 10
if Aufgabe == 'Planks 30s':
    Kalorien += 2.5
    Planks += 30
if Aufgabe == 'Planks 10s':
    Kalorien += 1
    Planks += 10
if Aufgabe == 'Hampelmann 10x':
    Kalorien += 10
    Hampelmann += 10

B = tk.Button(master=fenster, text ="Wiederholen", command = wiederholen )
B.config( height = 5, width = 50 )
B.pack()
Bu = tk.Button(master=fenster, text ="Statistiken", command = Kalorienzähler )
Bu.config( height = 5, width = 50 )
Bu.pack()
fenster.mainloop()
'''
```

I also want to write 'Liegestütze' before the int `Liegestützen` in `Liegestütze_fen`, but I don't know how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
Kalorien_fen = tk.Label(fenster1, text=f"Kalorien:{Kalorien}")
```

Or if you don't want to use f-strings/your Python version doesn't support them, you can do:

```py
Kalorien_fen = tk.Label(fenster1, text="Kalorien:" + str(Kalorien))
```

You can do something similar for `Liegestütze`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tryed These before and it doesn't work but These times it work with no issues.